Generating apk via bash
I'm trying to create an apk file using bash script:
#!/bin/bash

# Define the output directory
OUTPUT_DIR="/storage/emulated/0/Download/apks"

# Update and upgrade Termux
pkg update && pkg upgrade -y

# Install required packages
pkg install openjdk-17 -y
pkg install gradle -y

# Download and install Android SDK tools
mkdir -p ~/sdk-tools && cd ~/sdk-tools
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-7583922_latest.zip -O sdk-tools.zip
unzip sdk-tools.zip -d cmdline-tools
mkdir -p cmdline-tools/latest
mv cmdline-tools/cmdline-tools/* cmdline-tools/latest/

# Verify sdkmanager exists
if [ ! -f cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager ]; then
  echo "sdkmanager not found. Please check the extraction process."
  exit 1
fi

# Set up SDK root directory
mkdir -p ~/Android/Sdk
cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=${HOME}/Android/Sdk "platforms;android-24" "build-tools;24.0.3" "platform-tools"

# Create project structure
mkdir -p ~/MyFirstApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/myfirstapp
mkdir -p ~/MyFirstApp/app/src/main/res/values

# Create root build.gradle file
cat <<EOL > ~/MyFirstApp/build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
EOL

# Create app build.gradle file
cat <<EOL > ~/MyFirstApp/app/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
}
EOL

# Create MainActivity.java
cat <<EOL > ~/MyFirstApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/myfirstapp/MainActivity.java
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Hello, World!");
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
EOL

# Create AndroidManifest.xml
cat <<EOL > ~/MyFirstApp/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
EOL

# Create strings.xml
cat <<EOL > ~/MyFirstApp/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
</resources>
EOL

# Create styles.xml
cat <<EOL > ~/MyFirstApp/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
EOL

# Build the APK
cd ~/MyFirstApp
gradle wrapper
./gradlew build

# Check if Gradle build was successful
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Gradle build failed. Please check the logs for errors."
  exit 1
fi

# List the contents of the build output directory
echo "Listing contents of build output directory:"
ls -R app/build/outputs

# Ensure the output directory exists
mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIR

# Move the APK to the desired output directory
if [ -f app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk ]; then
    cp app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk $OUTPUT_DIR
    echo "APK has been moved to $OUTPUT_DIR/app-debug.apk"
else
    echo "APK was not found in the expected location."
    echo "Listing contents of app/build/outputs/apk directory for debugging:"
    ls -R app/build/outputs/apk
fi

In this code, I download gradle, java compiler and I'm trying to compile standard apk file. But when I want to move apk, I get an error:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Listing contents of build output directory:
ls: cannot access 'app/build/outputs': No such file or directory
APK was not found in the expected location.
Listing contents of app/build/outputs/apk directory for debugging:
ls: cannot access 'app/build/outputs/apk': No such file or directory
~ $

That's telling me that the apk file was not created, but I didn't find any problems.

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

It seems there are two issues with your script.

You have only defined the "release" build inside buildTypes of your build.gradle and using path for debug builds.
You are not using correct command to build apk.

As a solution I would recommend you to define a "debug" config in your inside buildTypes and use command
./gradlew assembleDebug

or alternatively use command
./gradlew assembleRelease

// but then apk output directory will also change to
// app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk

Check more about build configuration and flavors here
https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants#build-types

I tryed to use your variant, but i have error that this task is not found. I read docs and tryed tou use all 4 types of compiles: demo debug/release and full debug/release. I have the same trouble
